# ¿Como poner el slider debajo de lightbox?

Tags: javascript, css3

buen dia, estoy usando la libreria Nivo-slider.js, pero me surgio un problema, tengo un light-box, el problema es que cuando activo mi light box, el slide queda por encima de este, y no quiero que haga eso, alguna sugerencia, como puedo hacerle para que no pase esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como pueden ver la imagen que tengo en el light-box se oculta cuando el slide cambia de imagen, como puedo hacer para que no pase eso?

lo unico que se maneja para hacer el slider es esto:

HTML:

```
<div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
    <div class="nivoSlider" id="slider">
        <img src="<?= $refa ?>/img/Catalogo/Running/slide/slide11.jpg" alt="" class="img">
        <img src="<?=$refa ?>/img/Catalogo/Running/slide/slide2.jpg" alt="" class="img">
        <img src="<?=$refa ?>/img/Catalogo/Running/slide/slide3.jpg" alt="" class="img">
    </div>
    <div id="htmlcaption" class="nivo-html-caption">
        <strong>This</strong> is an example of a <em>HTML</em> caption with <a href="#">a link</a>.
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script src="<?= $refa ?>/js/jquery.nivo.slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider();
 });
</script>
```

CSS DEL LIGHT-BOX:

```
.lightbox{
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}

.lightbox img{
  width: 30%;
}

.btn-close{
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   background: #ff0505;
   border: 3px solid #fff;
   border-radius: 100%;
   color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  }
```

Comment: Si no compartes lo que has hecho hasta ahora se puede dificultar ayudarte y vas a recibir puntos negativos. Intenta compartir un fragmento del código que has hecho.

Comment: de cual codigo, del css??

Comment: Del html y del css.